# Is adding tasks to BlockingQueue of ThreadPoolExecutor advisable?

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer, executorservice, blockingqueue

The JavaDoc for [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is unclear on whether it is acceptable to add tasks directly to the `BlockingQueue` backing the executor. [The docs say](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getQueue%28%29) calling `executor.getQueue()` is "intended primarily for debugging and monitoring".

I'm constructing a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with my own `BlockingQueue`. I retain a reference to the queue so I can add tasks to it directly. The same queue is returned by `getQueue()` so I assume the admonition in `getQueue()` applies to a reference to the backing queue acquired through my means.

### Example

General pattern of the code is:

```
int n = ...; // number of threads
queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize);
executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(n, n, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, queue);
executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();
// ...
while (...) {
    Runnable job = ...;
    queue.offer(job, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
}
while (jobsOutstanding.get() != 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(...);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
executor.shutdownNow();
```

### `queue.offer()` vs `executor.execute()`

As I understand it, the typical use is to add tasks via `executor.execute()`. The approach in my example above has the benefit of blocking on the queue whereas `execute()` fails immediately if the queue is full and rejects my task. I also like that submitting jobs interacts with a blocking queue; this feels more "pure" producer-consumer to me.

An implication of adding tasks to the queue directly: I must call `prestartAllCoreThreads()` otherwise no worker threads are running. Assuming no other interactions with the executor, nothing will be monitoring the queue (examination of `ThreadPoolExecutor` source confirms this). This also implies for direct enqueuing that the `ThreadPoolExecutor` must additionally be configured for > 0 core threads and mustn't be configured to allow core threads to timeout.

### tl;dr

Given a `ThreadPoolExecutor` configured as follows:

- core threads > 0
- core threads aren't allowed to timeout
- core threads are prestarted
- hold a reference to the `BlockingQueue` backing the executor

Is it acceptable to add tasks directly to the queue instead of calling `executor.execute()`?

### Related

This question ( [producer/consumer work queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233561/producer-consumer-work-queues) ) is similar, but doesn't specifically cover adding to the queue directly.

Comment: "I retain a reference to the queue so I can add tasks to it directly" but why would you do that? Why not just submit them to the executor?

Comment: @Raedwald, see above where I write "The approach in my example above has the benefit of blocking on the queue..."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it were me, I would prefer using `Executor#execute()` over `Queue#offer()`, simply because I'm using everything else from `java.util.concurrent` already.

Your question is a good one, and it piqued my interest, so I took a look at the source for `ThreadPoolExecutor#execute()`:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (poolSize >= corePoolSize || !addIfUnderCorePoolSize(command)) {
        if (runState == RUNNING && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            if (runState != RUNNING || poolSize == 0)
                ensureQueuedTaskHandled(command);
        }
        else if (!addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(command))
            reject(command); // is shutdown or saturated
    }
}
```

We can see that execute itself calls `offer()` on the work queue, but not before doing some nice, tasty pool manipulations if necessary. For that reason, I'd think that it'd be advisable to use `execute()`; not using it may (although I don't know for certain) cause the pool to operate in a non-optimal way. However, I don't think that using `offer()` will *break* the executor - it looks like tasks are pulled off the queue using the following (also from ThreadPoolExecutor):

```
Runnable getTask() {
    for (;;) {
        try {
            int state = runState;
            if (state > SHUTDOWN)
                return null;
            Runnable r;
            if (state == SHUTDOWN)  // Help drain queue
                r = workQueue.poll();
            else if (poolSize > corePoolSize || allowCoreThreadTimeOut)
                r = workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            else
                r = workQueue.take();
            if (r != null)
                return r;
            if (workerCanExit()) {
                if (runState >= SHUTDOWN) // Wake up others
                    interruptIdleWorkers();
                return null;
            }
            // Else retry
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // On interruption, re-check runState
        }
    }
}
```

This `getTask()` method is just called from within a loop, so if the executor's not shutting down, it'd block until a new task was given to the queue (regardless of from where it came from).

*Note*: Even though I've posted code snippets from source here, we can't rely on them for a definitive answer - we should only be coding to the API. We don't know how the implementation of `execute()` will change over time.

Answer (score 11):

One trick is to implement a custom subclass of ArrayBlockingQueue and to override the offer() method to call your blocking version, then you can still use the normal code path.

```
queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize) {
  @Override public boolean offer(Runnable runnable) {
    try {
      return offer(runnable, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      // return interrupt status to caller
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

(as you can probably guess, i think calling offer directly on the queue as your normal code path is probably a bad idea).

Answer (score 4):

One can actually configure behavior of the pool when the queue is full, by specifying a `RejectedExecutionHandler` at instantiation. `ThreadPoolExecutor` defines four policies as inner classes, including `AbortPolicy`, `DiscardOldestPolicy`, `DiscardPolicy`, as well as my personal favorite, `CallerRunsPolicy`, which runs the new job in the controlling thread.

For example:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        nproc, // core size
        nproc, // max size
        60, // idle timeout
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(4096, true), // Fairness = true guarantees FIFO
        new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy() ); // If we have to reject a task, run it in the calling thread.
```

The behavior desired in the question can be obtained using something like:

```
public class BlockingPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        executor.getQueue.put(r); // Self contained, no queue reference needed.
    }
```

At some point the queue *must* be accessed. The best place to do so is in a self-contained `RejectedExecutionHandler`, which saves any code duplication or potenial bugs arising from direct manipulation of the queue at the scope of the pool object. Note that the handlers included in `ThreadPoolExecutor` themselves use `getQueue()`.

Comment: I like that you present another alternative. My perspective at the time I was working on this was that the ThreadPoolExecutor was an implementation detail. I can model producer/consumer with blocking queues and swap out the implementation of how the work is scheduled without changing client code.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very important question if the queue you're using is a completely different implementation from the standard in-memory `LinkedBlockingQueue` or `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

For instance if you're implementing the producer-consumer pattern using several producers on different machines, and use a queuing mechanism based on a separate persistence subsystem (like Redis), then the question becomes relevant on its own, even if you don't want a blocking `offer()` like the OP.

So the given answer, that `prestartAllCoreThreads()` has to be called (or enough times `prestartCoreThread()`) for the worker threads to be available and running, is important enough to be stressed.

Answer (score 0):

If required, we can also use a parking lot which separates main processing from rejected tasks -

```
    final CountDownLatch taskCounter = new CountDownLatch(TASKCOUNT);
    final List<Runnable> taskParking = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskPool = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1);
    RejectedExecutionHandler rejectionHandler = new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -->rejection reported - adding to parking lot " + r);
            taskCounter.countDown();
            taskParking.add(r);
        }
    };
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor =  new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 10, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS, taskPool, rejectionHandler);
    for(int i=0 ; i<TASKCOUNT; i++){
        //main 
        threadPoolExecutor.submit(getRandomTask());
    }
    taskCounter.await(TASKCOUNT * 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Checking the parking lot..." + taskParking);
    while(taskParking.size() > 0){
        Runnable r = taskParking.remove(0);
        System.out.println("Running from parking lot..." + r);
        if(taskParking.size() > LIMIT){
          waitForSometime(...);
        }
        threadPoolExecutor.submit(r);
    }
    threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
```