# Control Number of Threads in Java lambda in a Portable manner

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, java-8

I'm interested in controlling the number of threads used when executing a Java lambda expression in parallel. I'm aware of the solutions presented [here](http://blog.krecan.net/2014/03/18/how-to-specify-thread-pool-for-java-8-parallel-streams/), where we put the lambda in a ForkJoin pool to get specific behavior. However, I see nothing in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) that indicates a parallel stream must use the ForkJoin framework. So while I could certainly use this solution, I still want to know if there are any *guaranteed ways* to get this behavior in a portable manner. While I could certainly write some code where in the lambda expression I have to grab a semaphore to run, forcing a specific number of threads to be used - this doesn't actually prevent the excess threads from being created in the first place, and would be an additional overhead that slows everything down (and just ugly).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629247/where-does-say-that-javas-parallel-stream-operations-use-fork-join

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream

Comment: A lambda expression is just a fancy way of writing an anonymous inner class, hence the thing you need to control must be elsewhere.

Comment: No, the mapping to execution policies is not specified.  If you want fine-grained control over parallelism, you need to code it yourself; parallel streams will pick a reasonable policy -- but the only guaranteed control you have is to force sequentiality.

Comment: Thank you Brian for a concise answer. While I wouldn't call controlling the maximum number of threads particularly fine-grained, I think it would be a good addition in the future.

Comment: @Raff.Edward Yes, we are looking into what can be done to provide finer-grained control over execution policies without overly constraining the runtime's ability to make reasonable decisions.