# Fork/Join Framework implementation in Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, fork-join, forkjoinpool

[Official Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) says:

> Another implementation of the fork/join framework is used by methods
>   in the java.util.streams package

The only public classes I have found there are [AbstractTask](http://download.java.net/lambda/b68/docs/api/java/util/stream/op/AbstractTask.html) and [AbstractShortCircuitTask](http://aruld.info/dev/java/api/java/util/stream/op/AbstractShortCircuitTask.html) and it is abstract.

And I haven't found and ForkJoinPool implemenentation.

**Question**: so does it mean that we don't have any manual access to fork/join process in Stream API and cannot not use this implementation directly?

Comment: The [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) instance that is used by default is the [common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) and you can access that. The documentation you are referring to is outdated or misleading. Also, there is no `java.util.sream.op` package in the final implementation.

Comment: @SergiiGetman Looks like you are looking for this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream

Comment: StefanZobel, Eugene - thanks guys,i'll check it

Comment: This is a misleading wording. There is no “*another implementation of the fork/join framework*”. The Stream API just uses the Fork/Join framework, just like `parallelSort()`, as mentioned in the previous paragraph, uses F/J, but that doesn’t mean that there is anything related to F/J in the API. There are some related side effects due to the use of this framework, however, every developer should keep in mind that this is an (officially) unspecified implementation detail.

Comment: See also [Where does official documentation say that Java's parallel stream operations use fork/join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629247/where-does-official-documentation-say-that-javas-parallel-stream-operations-use)