# Does Collection.parallelStream() imply a happens-before relationship?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-memory-model

Consider this (completely contrived) Java code:

```
final List<Integer> s = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
final int[] a = new int[1];
a[0] = 100;
s.parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
    synchronized (a) {
        a[0] += i;
    }
});
System.out.println(a[0]);
```

Is this code guaranteed to output "106"?

It seems like it is not unless there is a *happens-before* relationship established by `parallelStream()`, by which we can know for sure that the first accesses to `a[0]` in the lambda will see `100` and not zero (according to my understanding of the Java memory model).

But `Collection.parallelStream()` is not documented to establish such a relationship...

The same question can be asked for the completion of the `parallelStream()` method invocation.

So am I missing something, or is it true that for correctness would the above code be required to look something like this instead:

```
final List<Integer> s = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
final int[] a = new int[1];
synchronized (a) {
    a[0] = 100;
}
s.parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
    synchronized (a) {
        a[0] += i;
    }
});
synchronized (a) {
    System.out.println(a[0]);
}
```

Or... does `parallelStream()` actually provide these *happens-before* relationships, and this simply a matter of some missing documentation?

I'm asking because from an API design perspective, it seems (to me at least) like this would be a logical thing to do... analogous to `Thread.start()`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure where it's specified, but I'm pretty sure there is some *happens-before* edge before running a stream pipeline, whether sequential or parallel. Otherwise all bets are off. You might populate a list, stream it to a set, and find it empty. On a side note, you can avoid synchronizing your `forEach()` actions by using [`forEachOrdered()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) instead.

Comment: Note that parallel streams internally use the ForkJoinPool ([though that's not well-documented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24629247/1553851)), which implements ExecutorService, along with the [visibility guarantees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) related to task submission.

Comment: I think we all agree that there's probably a happens-before edge in there somewhere, practically speaking. What bugs me is that this is not guaranteed and documented, so for correctness you have to assume there's not.

Comment: @shmosel I’m very sure that you are allowed to always assume a valid *result* being returned from a parallel stream’s terminal operation, i.e. in case of `collect(toSet())`, that would be the returned `Set`. But *side effects*, as performed by `peek` or `forEach` are a different beast…

Answer (score 1):

You really should avoid hitting variables 'outside' the pipeline. Even if you get it to work correctly performance will likely suffer. There are a lot of tools to achieve this built into the JDK. For example your use case is probably safer with something like:

```
Integer reduce = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)
            .parallel()
            .reduce(100, (accumulator, element) -> accumulator + element);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) is a list of actions that establish a happens-before relationship.
As you can see `parallelStream` is not mentioned there, so to answer your question: no, 
`parallelStream` by itself doesn't establish a happens-before relationship.

As to the first access reading zero - If the main thread sets 100 before the `parallelStream` is being processed, then each thread the `paralleStream` starts will see that value, quoting from the link:

> A call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started
>   thread.

BTW, your lambda expression usage is stateful, which is [discouraged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#stateful_lambda_expressions)

Comment: The logic in this answer is incorrect.  You seem to be assuming that that list and the JLS are the only places where *happens before* relationships are / may be specified.

Comment: The threads in the thread pool may have already started (this is of course one of the main goals of "thread pools" in the first place). So the guarantee provided by `Thread.start()` doesn't necessarily apply here.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the below code to guaranteed,

```
        final List<Integer> s = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(100);
        s.parallelStream()
                .forEach(atomicInteger::addAndGet);
        System.out.println(atomicInteger.get());
```

Using parallel stream for fewer numbers is not good practice.