# Why does the slow task block the other smaller tasks in this program that uses parallel streams?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

Following a question form a colleague about parallel streams I wrote the following code to test something out.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Runnable> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("Time : " + System.nanoTime() + " " + "Slow task");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int j = i;
            list.add(() -> System.out.println("Time : " + System.nanoTime() + " " + j));
        }
        list.parallelStream().forEach(r -> r.run());
    }
}
```

Strangely the output is always something like the following.

```
Time : 4096118049370412 61
Time : 4096118049567530 311
Time : 4096118049480238 217
Time : 4096118049652415 405
Time : 4096118049370678 436
Time : 4096118049370575 155
Time : 4096118049720639 437
Time : 4096118049719368 280
Time : 4096118049804630 281
Time : 4096118049684148 406
Time : 4096118049660398 218

TRUNCATED  

Time : 4096118070511768 669
Time : 4096118070675678 670
Time : 4096118070584951 426
Time : 4096118070704143 427
Time : 4096118070714441 428
Time : 4096118070722080 429
Time : 4096118070729569 430
Time : 4096118070736782 431
Time : 4096118070744069 432
Time : 4096118070751286 433
Time : 4096118070758554 434
Time : 4096118070765913 435
Time : 4096118070550370 930
Time : 4096118070800538 931
Time : 4096118070687425 671
Time : 4096118070813669 932
Time : 4096118070827794 672
Time : 4096118070866089 933
Time : 4096118070881358 673
Time : 4096118070895344 934
Time : 4096118070907608 674
Time : 4096118070920712 935
Time : 4096118070932934 675
Time : 4096118070945131 936
Time : 4096118070957850 676
Time : 4096118070982326 677
Time : 4096118070991158 678
Time : 4096118070999002 679
Time : 4096118071006501 680
Time : 4096118071017766 681
Time : 4096118071025766 682
Time : 4096118071033318 683
Time : 4096118071070603 684
Time : 4096118071080240 685
Time : 4096128063025914 Slow task
Time : 4096128063123940 0
Time : 4096128063148135 1
Time : 4096128063173285 2
Time : 4096128063176723 3
Time : 4096128063179939 4
Time : 4096128063183077 5
Time : 4096128063191001 6
Time : 4096128063194156 7
Time : 4096128063197273 8
Time : 4096128063200395 9
Time : 4096128063203581 10
Time : 4096128063206988 11
Time : 4096128063210155 12
Time : 4096128063213285 13
Time : 4096128063216411 14
Time : 4096128063219542 15
Time : 4096128063222733 16
Time : 4096128063232190 17
Time : 4096128063235653 18
Time : 4096128063238827 19
Time : 4096128063241962 20
Time : 4096128063245176 21
Time : 4096128063248296 22
Time : 4096128063251444 23
Time : 4096128063254557 24
Time : 4096128063257705 25
Time : 4096128063261566 26
Time : 4096128063264733 27
Time : 4096128063268115 28
Time : 4096128063272851 29

Process finished with exit code 0
```

That is, there is always some tasks waiting for the slow task to finish processing, even though all the other tasks have finished. I would assume that the slow task should take only one thread and all the other tasks should finish without any problem and only the slow task should take the full 10 seconds. I have 8 CPUs so the parallelism level is 7.

What could the reason be for this?

To add more information, the code is only for understanding purposes. I am not putting it anywhere in production.

Comment: did you get same output, for every execution? how many times have you executed this code?

Comment: IMHO there's a limit of tasks that run in parallel. You certainly don't want 1000 threads. This will use 1000MB of memory and likely cause OOM (at least 32 bit)

Comment: Did you try changing <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1000" />?

Comment: Recommended read: [Visualization of Java Stream parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34381805/2711488)

Comment: Also: Thread.sleep() is not appropriate when working with tasks. Tasks are a more advanced concept than threads. Use `scheduler.schedule(task, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` for a delaying concept that matches the concept of tasks.

Comment: @ThomasWeller for simulating a workload in a simple test case, `Thread.sleep` may be fine.

Comment: Sure, but then the behavior is totally normal, since you don't want to have 1000*100% CPU usage

Comment: @Deadpool I ran about 5 times. The same output comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There are some limited capabilities when it comes to work-stealing with streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283041/a-simple-list-parallelstream-in-java-8-stream-does-not-seem-to-do-work-stealin), so if a single thread has pegged itself for some work in other runners, that work will be blocked until it's finished processing other tasks.

You can visualize this by adding a *few* more debugging notes around your code...

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Runnable> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Long sleep - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("Time : " + System.nanoTime() + " " + "Slow task");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int j = i;
            list.add(() -> System.out.println("Time : " + System.nanoTime() + " " + j));
        }
        list.parallelStream().forEach(r -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            r.run();
            System.out.println();
        });
    }
}
```

Upon running this, I observe the following message come up:

```
Long sleep - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
```

...and about ten seconds later...

```
Time : 11525122027429 Slow task

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122204035 0

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122245739 1

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122267015 2

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122286921 3

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122306266 4

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122338787 5

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122357288 6

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122376716 7

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122395218 8

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122414165 9

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122432755 10

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122452805 11

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122472624 12

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122491380 13

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122514417 14

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122534550 15

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
Time : 11525122553751 16
```

So this implies that on my box, worker-4 had some work slated for it which couldn't be stolen based on the fact that there were some uneven chunks.  Note: if a thread is processing a task in a chunk, that work isn't going to be broken up any further.

```
[31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 32, 0]
```

If you were looking for a threading implementation which could steal work from threads which ran longer, it'd be best to use the work-stealing pool directly.

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Runnable> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Long sleep - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("Time : " + System.nanoTime() + " " + "Slow task");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int j = i;
            list.add(() -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("Time : " + System.nanoTime() + " " + j);
                System.out.println();
            });
        }


        final ExecutorService stealingPool = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        list.forEach(stealingPool::execute);
        stealingPool.shutdown();
        stealingPool.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

The above prints out a more tenable and more reasonable result at the end of the list:

```
Time : 12210445469314 Slow task
```

...which implies that all available work has been processed in the time allotted (15 seconds).