# Bounded Blocking queue in Java(programming exercise)

Tags: java, multithreading

This problem is LeetCode 1188 and stated [here](https://leetcode.ca/2019-03-02-1188-Design-Bounded-Blocking-Queue/). I am able to implement it using Java's
`synchronized` keyword. Pasting the problem here before asking my question.

**Implement a thread safe bounded blocking queue that has the following methods:**

- BoundedBlockingQueue(int capacity) The constructor initializes the queue with a maximum capacity.
- void enqueue(int element) Adds an element to the front of the queue. If the queue is full, the calling thread is blocked until the queue is no longer full.
- int dequeue() Returns the element at the rear of the queue and removes it. If the queue is empty, the calling thread is blocked until the queue is no longer empty.
- int size() Returns the number of elements currently in the queue.

I saw a solution [here](https://walkccc.me/LeetCode/problems/1188/). Pasting the solution has well(from the link).

```
class BoundedBlockingQueue {
  public BoundedBlockingQueue(int capacity) {
    this.enqueueSemaphore = new Semaphore(capacity);
  }

  public void enqueue(int element) throws InterruptedException {
    enqueueSemaphore.acquire();
    q.offer(element);
    dequeueSemaphore.release();
  }

  public int dequeue() throws InterruptedException {
    dequeueSemaphore.acquire();
    final int element = q.poll();
    enqueueSemaphore.release();
    return element;
  }

  public int size() {
    return q.size();
  }

  private Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
  private Semaphore enqueueSemaphore;
  private Semaphore dequeueSemaphore = new Semaphore(0);
}
```

Why is this implementation correct is what is bothering me? I understand why and how the semaphores are being used. What I don't understand is that the access to the `private Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>();` is not restricted when one thread is modifying it. I mean to say if one thread is mutating the queue, another can too. How is this correct? Should not the queue be guarded by a `mutex` as well apart from the use of semaphores? As per Java, the queue implementation being used is not thread safe.

Comment: Modifications are guarded by the semaphore, doesn't it make the access restricted?

Comment: Modifications are not guarded by a semaphore. That is the whole point of my question

Comment: What do you mean? When a thread wants to modify the queue, it need to use one of the public methods. Inside the public method it needs to acquire the semaphore first. If the semaphore is already acquired, it needs to wait for it to be released.

Comment: I am not going to each you the basic of that here, just google a producer consumer problem and the way it is described in Peter Galvin's book or any other standard thread tutorial

Comment: Ok, I've read the requirements and the code more carefully this time ;) You're just right, it's not a correct solution

Comment: What makes you think that this solution is in fact correct? That is, why are you asking this question?

Comment: nice @TomekK. tgdavies, I am trying to validate my understanding to know for sure. I think the sol is not correct but I am trying to ascertain that by asking the Q

Comment: If you think it doesn't work, add some sleeps to force the conditions under which you expect it to fail.

Comment: @trashgod, trying to understand what you are implying by
->Note the comment, missing in the second link, "use key word synchronized to control queue access from different threads."

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to be skeptical. Synchronizing access to data shared among different threads is easy to get wrong, and testing may be inconsistent. Happily, [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) recapitulates the [*Memory Consistency Properties*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility), which may be used to reason about the proposed solution. In general:

> Each action in a thread *happens-before* every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.

Moreover, each [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) has a particular memory consistency effect:

> Actions in a thread prior to calling a "release" method such as `release()` *happen-before* actions following a successful "acquire" method such as `acquire()` in another thread.

Finally, the intended [usage](https://leetcode.ca/2019-03-02-1188-Design-Bounded-Blocking-Queue/) must be considered:

> [It] will be tested using multiple threads at the same time. Each thread will either be a producer thread that only makes calls to the `enqueue` method or a consumer thread that only makes calls to the `dequeue` method.

**Example 1.** One consumer thread; one producer thread. Because each mutation of `q` *happens-before* a semaphore is released and subsequently acquired on the opposite thread, each thread sees a consistent view of the `ArrayDeque`. The two semaphores act in concert to preclude deadlock, as when a producer blocks waiting for a permit and a consumer has yet to release one.

**Example 2.** Four consumer threads; three producer threads. In this case the actions remain correctly ordered, but the competing threads deadlock fairly promptly in what appears to be *pool-induced deadlock*, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23480863/230513). One remediation is suggested in a subsequent comment in the [example](https://leetcode.ca/2019-03-02-1188-Design-Bounded-Blocking-Queue/), which notifies waiting producers that a permit has become available or idle consumers that an element has become available.

> Use key word `synchronized` to control queue access from different threads.