# ParallelStream queue task in CommonPool rather than the custom pool

Tags: java, java-8, threadpool, mdc, forkjoinpool

I wanted to use custom ThreadPool for parallelStream. Reason being I wanted to use MDCContext in the task. This is the code I wrote to use the custom ThreadPool:

```
final ExecutorService mdcPool = MDCExecutors.newCachedThreadPool();
mdcPool.submit(() -> ruleset.getOperationList().parallelStream().forEach(operation -> {
                log.info("Sample log line");
});
```

When the MDC context was not getting copied to the task, I looked at the logs. These are the logs I found. The first log is executed in "(pool-16-thread-1)" but other tasks are getting executed on "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker". The first log also has MdcContextID. But as I am using custom ThreadPool for submitting the task, all tasks should be executing in custom ThreadPool.

```
16 Oct 2018 12:46:58,298 [INFO] 8fcfa6ee-d141-11e8-b84a-7da6cd73aa0b (pool-16-thread-1) com.amazon.rss.activity.business.VariablesEvaluator: Sample log line
16 Oct 2018 12:46:58,298 [INFO]  (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11) com.amazon.rss.activity.business.VariablesEvaluator: Sample log line
16 Oct 2018 12:46:58,298 [INFO]  (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4) com.amazon.rss.activity.business.VariablesEvaluator: Sample log line
16 Oct 2018 12:46:58,298 [INFO]  (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13) com.amazon.rss.activity.business.VariablesEvaluator: Sample log line
16 Oct 2018 12:46:58,298 [INFO]  (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9) com.amazon.rss.activity.business.VariablesEvaluator: Sample log line
16 Oct 2018 12:46:58,299 [INFO]  (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2) com.amazon.rss.activity.business.VariablesEvaluator: Sample log line
16 Oct 2018 12:46:58,299 [INFO]  (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15) com.amazon.rss.activity.business.VariablesEvaluator: Sample log line
```

Is this supposed to happen or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for running a parallel stream in a custom thread pool. It *happens* to be executed in a different Fork/Join pool when the operation is initiated in a worker thread of a different Fork/Join pool, but that does not seem to be a planned feature, as the Stream implementation code will still use artifacts of the common pool internally in some operations then.

In your case, it seems that the `ExecutorService` returned by `MDCExecutors.newCachedThreadPool()` is not a Fork/Join pool, so it does not exhibit this undocumented behavior at all.

There is a feature request, [JDK-8032512](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8032512), regarding more thread control. It’s open and, as far as I can see, without much activity.

Comment: me very confused right now :| what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269778/1059372)? Or you mean it *has* to be another `ForkJoinPool`?

Comment: @Eugene as said, it *happens* to work this way (when the custom pool is a Fork/Join pool), as the result of an implementation detail, not a planned feature. Compare with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29272776/2711488) where Stuart Marks explicitly states that this trick is not guaranteed to work and also describes one of the issues I meant with “the Stream implementation code will still use artifacts of the common pool internally”.

Comment: this somehow impacts me (almost directly) quite a lot, it seems. I wrote a few places where I use a custom parallel stream to run in a separate ForkJoinPool as I don't want to be blocked in case someone else uses the default one, it seems that I need to reconsider the code, but I might be out of alternatives. thank you for the comment