# Strange dead-lock with Streams API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was working a program, and decided to use the new Streams API for Java 8. However, my program stopped working when I introduced `.parallel()`. Here's the relevant code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import com.google.common.cache.*;

public class Alg196 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add .parallel() where suitable
        long c = Stream
                .iterate(BigInteger.valueOf(101), i -> i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
                .limit(100000000).map(BigInteger::toString).map(Alg196::alg196)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull).count();
        System.err.println(c);
    }

    private static final String reverse(String n) {
        return new StringBuilder(n).reverse().toString();
    }

    private static final boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        for (int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static final String alg196(String n) {
        System.err.println("PROCESSING " + n);
        int loops = 0;
        while (!isPalindrome(n)) {
            n = new BigInteger(n).add(new BigInteger(reverse(n))).toString();
            loops++;
            if (loops >= 100) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        if (loops <= 10) {
            return null;
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

The output will contain many `PROCESSING <x>` lines when working correctly, but that never happens with `.parallel()`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program didn't stop - it's working hard trying to generate requested range of BigIntegers (in your case it is 100000000) before submitting map tasks to executors (try to put breakpoint at BigInteger::add() method - and you'll see)

it's also easy to see from thread dump

```
"ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2@710" daemon prio=5 tid=0xe nid=NA runnable java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.util.stream.Stream$1.next(Stream.java:1033)
  at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.trySplit(Spliterators.java:1784)
  at java.util.stream.AbstractShortCircuitTask.compute(AbstractShortCircuitTask.java:114)
  at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:902)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1644)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)`
```

Also please be careful submitting many long-running tasks to the common ForkJoin pool, as you may block all threads in the pool - you can check this thread ([Custom thread pool in Java 8 parallel stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream)) for solution

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `limit` is a short-circuiting operation, which means it will generate all `100,000,000` `BigIntegers` before running anything else. Not a dead-lock after all!