# Encounter Order wrong when sorting a parallel stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Record` class:

```
public class Record implements Comparable<Record>
{
   private String myCategory1;
   private int    myCategory2;
   private String myCategory3;
   private String myCategory4;
   private int    myValue1;
   private double myValue2;

   public Record(String category1, int category2, String category3, String category4,
      int value1, double value2)
   {
      myCategory1 = category1;
      myCategory2 = category2;
      myCategory3 = category3;
      myCategory4 = category4;
      myValue1 = value1;
      myValue2 = value2;
   }

   // Getters here
}
```

I create a big list of a lot of records.  Only the second and fifth values, `i / 10000` and `i`, are used later, by the getters `getCategory2()` and `getValue1()` respectively.

```
List<Record> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 115000; i++)
{
    list.add(new Record("A", i / 10000, "B", "C", i, (double) i / 100 + 1));
}
```

Note that first 10,000 records have a `category2` of `0`, then next 10,000 have `1`, etc., while the `value1` values are 0-114999 sequentially.

I create a `Stream` that is both `parallel` and `sorted`.

```
Stream<Record> stream = list.stream()
   .parallel()
   .sorted(
       //(r1, r2) -> Integer.compare(r1.getCategory2(), r2.getCategory2())
   )
   //.parallel()
;
```

I have a `ForkJoinPool` that maintains `8` threads, which is the number of cores I have on my PC.

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(8);
```

I use the trick [described here to submit a stream processing task to my own `ForkJoinPool` instead of the common `ForkJoinPool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream).

```
List<Record> output = pool.submit(() ->
    stream.collect(Collectors.toList()
)).get();
```

I expected that the parallel `sorted` operation would respect the encounter order of the stream, and that it would be a *stable* sort, because the `Spliterator` returned by `ArrayList` is `ORDERED`.

However, simple code that prints out the elements of the resultant `List` `output` in order shows that it's not quite the case.

```
for (Record record : output)
{
     System.out.println(record.getValue1());
}
```

Output, condensed:

```
0
1
2
3
...
69996
69997
69998
69999
71875  // discontinuity!
71876
71877
71878
...
79058
79059
79060
79061
70000  // discontinuity!
70001
70002
70003
...
71871
71872
71873
71874
79062  // discontinuity!
79063
79064
79065
79066
...
114996
114997
114998
114999
```

The `size()` of `output` is `115000`, and all elements appear to be there, just in a slightly different order.

So I wrote some checking code to see if the `sort` was stable.  If it's stable, then all of the `value1` values should remain in order.  This code verifies the order, printing any discrepancies.

```
int prev = -1;
boolean verified = true;
for (Record record : output)
{
    int curr = record.getValue1();
    if (prev != -1)
    {
        if (prev + 1 != curr)
        {
            System.out.println("Warning: " + prev + " followed by " + curr + "!");
            verified = false;
        }
    }
    prev = curr;
}
System.out.println("Verified: " + verified);
```

Output:

```
Warning: 69999 followed by 71875!
Warning: 79061 followed by 70000!
Warning: 71874 followed by 79062!
Warning: 99999 followed by 100625!
Warning: 107811 followed by 100000!
Warning: 100624 followed by 107812!
Verified: false
```

This condition persists if I do any of the following:

- Replace the `ForkJoinPool` with a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

  ```
  ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8, 8, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10));
  ```
- Use the common `ForkJoinPool` by processing the `Stream` directly.

  ```
  List<Record> output = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- Call `parallel()` *after* I call `sorted`.

  ```
  Stream<Record> stream = list.stream().sorted().parallel();
  ```
- Call `parallelStream()` instead of `stream().parallel()`.

  ```
  Stream<Record> stream = list.parallelStream().sorted();
  ```
- Sort using a `Comparator`.  Note that this sort criterion is different that the "natural" order I defined for the `Comparable` interface, although starting with the results already in order from the beginning, the result should still be the same.

  ```
  Stream<Record> stream = list.stream().parallel().sorted(
      (r1, r2) -> Integer.compare(r1.getCategory2(), r2.getCategory2())
  );
  ```

I can only get this to preserve the encounter order if I don't do one of the following on the `Stream`:

- Don't call `parallel()`.
- Don't call any overload of `sorted`.

Interestingly, the `parallel()` without a sort preserved the order.

In both of the above cases, the output is:

```
Verified: true
```

My Java version is 1.8.0_05.  This anomaly also [occurs on Ideone](http://ideone.com/vli0tC), which appears to be running Java 8u25.

**Update**

I've upgraded my JDK to the latest version as of this writing, 1.8.0_45, and the problem is unchanged.

**Question**

Is the record order in the resultant `List` (`output`) out of order because the sort is somehow not stable, because the encounter order is not preserved, or some other reason?

How can I ensure that the encounter order is preserved when I create a parallel stream and sort it?

Comment: I would try making the simplest program reproducing the problem, running it on the latest JDK version, and submit a bug if it's reproduced: the sort is supposed to be stable: it's documented as such.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like `Arrays.parallelSort` isn't stable in some circumstances. Well spotted. The stream parallel sort is implemented in terms of `Arrays.parallelSort`, so it affects streams as well. Here's a simplified example:

```
public class StableSortBug {
    static final int SIZE = 50_000;

    static class Record implements Comparable<Record> {
        final int sortVal;
        final int seqNum;

        Record(int i1, int i2) { sortVal = i1; seqNum = i2; }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Record other) {
            return Integer.compare(this.sortVal, other.sortVal);
        }
    }

    static Record[] genArray() {
        Record[] array = new Record[SIZE];
        Arrays.setAll(array, i -> new Record(i / 10_000, i));
        return array;
    }

    static boolean verify(Record[] array) {
        return IntStream.range(1, array.length)
                        .allMatch(i -> array[i-1].seqNum + 1 == array[i].seqNum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Record[] array = genArray();
        System.out.println(verify(array));
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(verify(array));
        Arrays.parallelSort(array);
        System.out.println(verify(array));
    }
}
```

On my machine (2 core x 2 threads) this prints the following:

```
true
true
false
```

Of course, it's supposed to print `true` three times. This is on the current JDK 9 dev builds. I wouldn't be surprised if it occurs in all the JDK 8 releases thus far, given what you've tried. Curiously, reducing the size or the divisor will change the behavior. A size of 20,000 and a divisor of 10,000 is stable, and a size of 50,000 and a divisor of 1,000 is also stable. It seems like the problem has to do with a sufficiently large run of values comparing equal versus the parallel split size.

The OpenJDK issue [JDK-8076446](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8076446) covers this bug.

Comment: (true, true, false) also on Windows7 (64),8u40.

Comment: @StefanZobel Oh yes, thanks, I've closed the new bug as a duplicate of the old one.

Comment: @StuartMarks Thanks for identifying the root cause of this bug.  Do we know when it will be fixed?  Will a fix be applied to Java 8 or just Java 9 development going forward?

Comment: @rgettman Sorry, no estimate on this. Personally I'd recommend that a fix be backported to the 8-update release line, but I can't make any promises about whether that will happen.