# Java 8 stream parallelism: set number of threads to use?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

Reading Java 8's streaming API for parallelism:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

It's not clear how to tune the number of threads to use when using this streaming API's parallelism?

Plan to run this on a very specific type of machine and a consistent data types, so I was thinking I can benchmark it over a set of different settings then use the best number of threads.

Answer (score 4):

The stream API does not support *any* tuning parameters.  The library is designed to work as effectively as possible regardless of the particular machine's characteristics.

Comment: Then using traditional threads would be appropriate?

Comment: I didn't say that.  I would trust the stream API to be better implemented than anything you wrote from scratch, even if you had information about the machine.

Comment: To put it another way, there are no tuning parameters because it knows better than you.

Comment: Well, there is that system property I guess.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it ALWAYS knows better than you. Tuning would have been useful when the processing is IO-bound. Consider something like map(StockUtil::getPrice()) that goes to a web service to get the price for the 1000 ticker symbols in the list.

Comment: @Louis I strongly disagree. I'm trying to run slow network requests in parallel on a backend server. Probably I need to use the undocumented [ForkJoinPool-Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269778/2448440), which is IMO worse than adding an optional parameter for a max number of threads. -.-

Comment: @Qw3ry: streams are not intended for that use case.  Streams are intended for local, computational work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman is this intention documented somewhere? Because for me, Streams feel like a (general purpose) language construct (it is `java.*lang*.stream.Stream` after all). In some cases I might not even know (or care) how my data is processed (in my concrete case I'm looking into caching right now - that will actually change the _how is my data processed_ during runtime).