# SecurityException from I/O code in a parallel stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, securitymanager

I have no way to explain this one, but I found this phenomenon in somebody else's code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestDidWeBreakJavaAgain
{
    @Test
    public void testIoInSerialStream()
    {
        doTest(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIoInParallelStream()
    {
        doTest(true);
    }

    private void doTest(boolean parallel)
    {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("1", "2", "3");
        if (parallel)
        {
            stream = stream.parallel();
        }
        stream.forEach(name -> {
            try
            {
                Files.createTempFile(name, ".dat");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new UncheckedIOException("Failed to create temp file", e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When run with the security manager enabled, merely calling `parallel()` on a stream, or `parallelStream()` when getting the stream from a collection, seems to guarantee that all attempts to perform I/O will throw `SecurityException`. (Most likely, calling any method which *can* throw `SecurityException`, *will* throw.)

I understand that `parallel()` means that it will be running in another thread which might not have the same privileges as the one we started with, but I guess I thought that the framework would take care of that for us.

Removing calls to `parallel()` or `parallelStream()` throughout the codebase avoids the risk. Inserting an `AccessController.doPrivileged` also fixes it, but doesn't sound safe to me, at least not in all situations. Is there any other option?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of an exception you get

Comment: Also please add your `SecurityManager` code so we can reproduce your problem exactly.

Comment: This has possibly to do with parallel streams using the common fork join pool. How does it work [if you provide your own pool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22269778/829571)?

Comment: This problem also affects context stored in `ThreadLocal` such as Spring's `SecurityContext`, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48076410/587365)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parallel stream execution will use the Fork/Join framework, more specifically it will use the Fork/Join common pool. This is an implementation detail, but as observed in this case such details can leak out in unexpected ways.

Note that the same behaviour can also occur when executing a task asynchronously using `CompletableFuture`.

When a security manager is present the thread factory of the Fork/Join common pool is set to a factory that creates *innocuous* threads. Such an *innocuous* thread has no permissions granted to it, is not a member of any defined thread group, and after a top-level Fork/Join task has completed its execution all thread locals (if created) are cleared.  Such behaviour ensures Fork/Join tasks are isolated from each other when sharing the common pool.

This is why in the example a `SecurityException` is thrown, probably:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file or directory

There are two potential work arounds. Depending on the reasons a security manager utilized, each work around may increase the risk of being insecure.

The first, more general, work around is to register a Fork/Join thread factory via  a system property to tell the Fork/Join framework what the default thread factory should be for the common pool. For example here is a really simple thread factory:

```
public class MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory
        implements ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {
    public final ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
        return new ForkJoinWorkerThread(pool) {};
    }
}
```

Which can be registered with the following system property:

> -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory

The behaviour of `MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` is currently equivalent to that of 
[`ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory).

The second, more specific, work around is to create a new Fork/Join pool. In this case the `ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` will be utilized for constructors not accepting a `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` argument. Any parallel stream execution would need to be performed from within a task executed from within that pool. Note that this is an implementation detail and may or may not work in future releases.

Comment: Good answer. Also be aware that the submitting thread may be used as a worker thread in the F/J framework which may have an impact here:
http://coopsoft.com/ar/Calamity2Article.html#submit

Comment: Interestingly, even constructing a new ForkJoinPool without customising anything produces a pool which gives me full permissions. It's only the instance which comes from commonPool() which has been "poisoned" by their custom factory. The Stream API doesn't appear to give me the ability to choose which pool is used anyway, so I guess we will just have to avoid using it and use our existing parallel execution utilities.

Comment: Trejkaz, you are correct, i missed that when eyeballing the code. Answer updated to correct the mistake.

Comment: I just wanted to note that when debugging `SecurityManager` permission issues, [Oracle's troubleshooting guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/troubleshooting-security.html) can be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your worrying about `AccessController.doPrivileged` is unnecessary. It does not reduce the security *if done right*. The versions taking a single action argument will execute the action in your context, ignoring your callers but there are overloaded methods, having an additional argument, a previously recorded context:

```
private void doTest(boolean parallel)
{
    Consumer<String> createFile=name -> {
        try {
            Files.createTempFile(name, ".dat");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException("Failed to create temp file", e);
        }
    }, actualAction;
    Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("1", "2", "3");

    if(parallel)
    {
        stream = stream.parallel();
        AccessControlContext ctx=AccessController.getContext();
        actualAction=name -> AccessController.doPrivileged(
          (PrivilegedAction<?>)()->{ createFile.accept(name); return null; }, ctx);
    }
    else actualAction = createFile;

    stream.forEach(actualAction);
}
```

The first important line is the `AccessControlContext ctx=AccessController.getContext();` statement it records your current security context which includes your code *and* the current callers. (Remember that the effective permissions are the *intersection* of the sets of all callers). By providing the resulting context object `ctx` to the `doPrivileged` method within the `Consumer` you are reestablishing the context, in other words, the `PrivilegedAction` will have the same permissions as in your single-threaded scenario.