# Null principal when get security context in parallelStream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, stream

When I try to obtain the principal from the security context in a parallel stream, it always returns null when isn't in the main thread.

The following piece of code fails when the user is authenticated:

```
listOfSomething.parallelStream()
                .foreach(el -> { 
if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() == null){
            throw new RuntimeException();
}});
```

The documentation says:

> Interface defining the minimum security information associated with
>   the current thread of execution.

But, is there any way to do it? It starts in main thread and use ForkJoinPool

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a duplicate. In the linked question, OP spawned a thread explicitly, and attempted to access `SecurityContext` from that thread. In such a case, we are dealing with a child thread, and  `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` successfully propagates the `SecurityContext`. Here, we are using `parallelStream()` which will use threads from the fork/join pool (implementation dependent) which may not be children of the initiating thread.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31052486/587365) might be a more helpful pointer. I haven't yet validated it myself for the case of `SecurityContext` propagation during parallel stream operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need to use a different `SecurityContextHolder` strategy. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#securitycontextholder-securitycontext-and-authentication-objects for more details on how to change it

Comment: Cool! Thank you! The mode that I'm looking for is `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`

Comment: *Don't do this!* Security context should not be used in parallel streams. 
`ParallelStream` uses a commonly shared `ForkJoinPool.commonPool`, and `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL ` will result in pretty nasty security issue described here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6856.

If you desperately need to use a parallel stream, then you need to bind it to a custom ForkJoinPool which is not shared between different application users. See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream