# Parallel Stream and SpringSecurity

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-security, parallelstream

I have the following block of code:

```
myList.parallelStream().forEach(item -> {
  //this external api call will use the current
  //spring security to populate the headers with values
  //that is extracted from jwt token

  var response = externalApi.getFoo(item.getAttribute());

  ..do something..

});
```

The problem is, the SecurityContext does not get passed from 1 thread to another.
I get null pointer when getting the Authentication principal.
Is there a correct way of doing this?

One that does NOT involve setting the SecurityContextHolder's strategy to MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL?
I believe this can cause security issues if there are multiple users accessing the service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null principal when get security context in parallelStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076410/null-principal-when-get-security-context-in-parallelstream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply set the authentication information to each thread.
Do you find any problem with this approach?

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
myList.parallelStream().forEach(item -> {
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
  var response = externalApi.getFoo(item.getAttribute());
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);

  ..do something..

});
```

Comment: See the answers here and why not to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48076704/9224219

Comment: I looked into your link and i think you are missing the point or somebody changed their stuff. What is wrong with explicitly transfer the security context to the other thread context? He even resets it to null.

Comment: Ok maybe use try/finally.