# How to reduce # of threads in Java parallelStream?

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have a test code with `parallelStream()` that sends requests to a server machine.

```
Report report = 
    requestsList.parallelStream()
                .map(request -> freshResultsGenerator.getResponse(request, e2EResultLongBL))
                .map(response -> resultsComparer.compareToBl(response, e2EResultLongBL,
                            astarHistogramsArrayBl, latencyHistogramBl))
                .reduce(null,
                        (sumReport, compare2) ->
                        {
                            if (sumReport == null) {
                                sumReport = new Report();
                            }
                            sumReport.add(compare2);
                            return sumReport;
                        },
                        (report1, report2) ->
                        {
                            Report report3 = new Report();
                            report3.add(report1);
                            report3.add(report2);
                            return report3;
                        });
```

The loads are too much for this machine and very quickly it returns HTTP 404 errors.

There are two things I didn't find an answer on Google:

1. What is the default # of threads for parallelStream, if not customed
   set?
2. How can I set the number of worker threads to, say, 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stream API uses [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) to execute concurrent tasks. Quoting its documentation:

> The common pool is by default constructed with default parameters, but these may be controlled by setting three system properties:
>
> - `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` - the parallelism level, a non-negative integer
>     
>   ...

Also

> a `ForkJoinPool` may be constructed with a given target parallelism level; by default, equal to the number of available processors.

So to customize the number of threads, you can set the system property `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` to the value you want:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "4")
```

to set the number of worker threads to 4. By default, the number of threads will be equal to the number of processors you have.

Comment: Changing the property would be good to change the default value. If you need different values for different streams using a dedicated ForkJoinPool would be the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

`ParallelStream` uses `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` which is initialized to your **number of cores - 1**.

It it possible to pass your own `ForkJoin Executor` to parallelStream as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream), but the executor has to be a ForkJoin, which is not the best for IO bound tasks.

Comment: thanks. why is "which is not the best for IO bound tasks."?

Comment: @EladBenda any fork join executor

Answer (score 1):

You may launch your pipeline inside the custom `ForkJoinPool` and it will be used to get the result:

```
ForkJoinPool fjp = new ForkJoinPool(2);
System.out.println("My pool: " + fjp);
String result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
    () -> Stream.of("a", "b", "c").parallel()
    .peek(x -> System.out.println(
        ((ForkJoinWorkerThread) Thread.currentThread()).getPool()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining()), fjp).join();
System.out.println(result);
```

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library adds a syntactic sugar method `.parallel(fjp)` to make this simpler:

```
String result = StreamEx.of("a", "b", "c")
    .parallel(fjp)
    .peek(x -> System.out.println(
        ((ForkJoinWorkerThread) Thread.currentThread()).getPool()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```