# Java parallelstream not using optimal number of threads when using newCachedThreadPool()

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-stream, executorservice

I have made two separate implementations of parallel reads from database.
First implementation is using `ExecutorService` with `newCachedThreadPool()` constructor and Futures: I simply make a call that returns a future for each read case and then after I make all the calls I call `get()` on them. This implementation works OK and is fast enough.

The second implementation is using parallel streams. When I put parallel stream call into the same `ExecutorService` pool it works almost **5 times slower** and it seems that it is not using as many threads as I would hope. When I instead put it into `ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(50)` then it works as fast as the previous implementation.

**My question is:**

Why do parallel streams under-utilize threads in `newCachedThreadPool` version?

Here is the code for the second implementation (I am not posting the first implementation, cause that one works OK anyway):

```
private static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

final List<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String>> simpleImmutableEntryStream =
                personIdList.stream().flatMap(
                        personId -> movieIdList.stream().map(
                                movieId -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(personId, movieId))).collect(Collectors.toList());

final Future<Map<String, List<Summary>>> futureMovieSummaryForPerson = pool.submit(() -> {
      final Stream<Summary> summaryStream = simpleImmutableEntryStream.parallelStream().map(
            inputPair -> {
                   return FeedbackDao.find(inputPair.getKey(), inputPair.getValue());
            }).filter(Objects::nonNull);
return summaryStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Summary::getPersonId));
});
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: When I replace the first line of the code with: "ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(50);" then it works fast again.

Comment: According to your code, you submit only task, right? or I miss something?

Comment: I submit parallelstream.map, which will create multiple asynchronous tasks, each of which makes a call to the database. If I call parallelstream.map without putting it into the pool, then it will by default use ForkJoinPool with number of threads limited by number of processors, which I didn't want.

Comment: Are you sure? for me you submit only one task to your pool and this task calls simpleImmutableEntryStream.parallelStream() that  will internally use its own ForkJoinPool pool not yours

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream

Comment: Also I did verify that this actually does create multiple threads (I logged Thread.currentThread().getId()). It's just that the number of threads is surprisingly low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to how [ForkJoinTask.fork](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#fork--) is implemented, if the current thread comes from a `ForkJoinPool` it will use the same pool to submit the new tasks but if not it will use the common pool with the total amount of processors in your local machine and here when you create your pool with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, the thread created by this pool is not recognized as coming from a `ForkJoinPool` such that it uses the common pool.

Here is how it is implemented, it should help you to better understand:

```
public final ForkJoinTask<V> fork() {
    Thread t;
    if ((t = Thread.currentThread()) instanceof ForkJoinWorkerThread)
        ((ForkJoinWorkerThread)t).workQueue.push(this);
    else
        ForkJoinPool.common.externalPush(this);
    return this;
}
```

The thread created by the pool `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` will not be of type `ForkJoinWorkerThread` such that it will use the common pool with an under optimized pool size to submit the new tasks.

Comment: I have added the code for this implementation. As you can see I am not using default pool for parallelstream, but instead run it within a separately created ExecutorService with flexible number of threads.

Comment: Thx for the link, it actually gives you the answer

Comment: I see. You are right. Does this mean that I cannot run parallel streams in an "unbounded" pool? Do you know if there is a way to have cached pool in ForkJoinPool?

Comment: good question, I don't know, maybe you could submit a new question for that