# Set java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism java property?

Tags: java

Can we set java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism java property?

```
System.out.println("getParallelism=" +ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getParallelism());
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism","20");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("getParallelism=" +ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getParallelism());
```

prints:

```
getParallelism=3
getParallelism=3
```

Comment: If you change the second line to `System.out.println(System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism","20"));`, does it indicate a previous value of 3 for that property?

Comment: The common parallelism property is set once per initialization of class `ForkJoinPool` , and cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: I think while creating your ForkJoinPool you can pass this value to the factory method.

Comment: @NareshJoshi, that is true, but there is no ability to affect the `commonPool()` like that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to set the parameter before the application starts. So passing a JVM parameter

`-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=20`

at startup will change it to 20.

Comment: can get this property during runtime inside your container by a specifc command line ?

Answer (score 4):

Otherwise you can create your custom pool and achieve the parallelism you want

```
int numTasks = 20;
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(numTasks);
System.out.println("getCustomParallelism=" +pool.getParallelism()); //prints 20
```

Comment: When this question was asked, I was trying to override the number of threads that were used in Stream.parallel() so overring the default pool is the only solution (at least, that's what I know)

Comment: Aha, I can get your point now. I found this link to help in your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic setting works when it is the first statement accessing the pool. Try removing the first line which gets and prints the default parallelism. Use just the below.

```
    System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism","20");
    System.out.println("getParallelism=" +ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getParallelism());
```