# custom naming for threads using threadfactory

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a class that represent the `world` where subjects live in

```
public class WorldLifecycle {
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public void startWorld() {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
            r -> {
                String id = ((IdentifiableRunnable) r).getId();
                return new Thread(r, id);
            });
    }

    public void bringLife(LivingPerson ... people) {
        Arrays.stream(people).forEach(executorService::submit);
    }

    public void endWorld() {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to finish thread executor!");
        }
    }
}
```

Every `LivingPerson` looks like this

```
public class LivingPerson implements IdentifiableRunnable {
    // investigate global world variable
    private boolean isRunning = true;

    private final StatefulPerson person;

    public LivingPerson(StatefulPerson person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Initial state: person=" + person.getRawPerson());
        while (isRunning) { // for now forever
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // do transition every 1 seconds

                LifeState state = person.nextState();
                System.out.println(getPerson().getName() + " " + state.getActionLabel());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End state: person=" + person.getRawPerson());
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        Person person = getPerson();
        return person.getId() + " - " + person.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void terminate() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    // returns clone instead of existing
    private Person getPerson() {
        return person.getRawPerson();
    }

}
```

I want to name each thread by using person's name and unique identifier.

`IdentifiableRunnable` is a simple interface

```
public interface IdentifiableRunnable extends Runnable {
    String getId();
    void terminate();
}
```

I initialize everything like this

```
WorldLifecycle world = new WorldLifecycle();
LivingPerson male = createPerson("John", 40, Gender.MALE);
LivingPerson female = createPerson("Helen", 25, Gender.FEMALE);

System.out.println("Starting world...");
world.startWorld();

world.bringLife(male, female);

// just wait
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

System.out.println("Destroying world...");
world.endWorld();
```

But when I try to run it, I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker cannot be cast to com.lapots.breed.lifecycle.api.Ide
ntifiableRunnable
at com.lapots.breed.lifecycle.WorldLifecycle.lambda$startWorld$0(WorldLifecycle.java:14)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:612)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:925)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1357)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at com.lapots.breed.lifecycle.WorldLifecycle.bringLife(WorldLifecycle.java:20)
at com.lapots.breed.Sandbox.main(Sandbox.java:23)
```

As it seems it does not get my `identifiableRunnable` in the `ThreadFactory`. 
How to solve it?

Comment: Not your down-voter, but in the future, please consider posting a valid [mcve]. Your code above has much bloat that is completely unrelated to the problem at hand, and you could reproduce the problem with 1/4 the code you've given.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what will you be using the thread id's for? I have to wonder if this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in disguise.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have no particular use for ids though for now. But decided to set them just in case if a `living person` fails due to some issue - easier to track which character's behavior is odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you trace library calls with a debugger you will notice that your `newThread` method will be called like so:

```
Worker(Runnable firstTask) {
    setState(-1); // inhibit interrupts until runWorker
    this.firstTask = firstTask;
    this.thread = getThreadFactory().newThread(this);
}
```

So it is passed an instance of the `Worker` class, which obviously can't be cast to your `IdentifiableRunnable`.

To execute your stream in parallel you should use `ForkJoinPool` how it is described in this post, in the first answer  [Custom thread pool in Java 8 parallel stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream)

Btw, here's how you can compress the code in your post:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    interface TestInterface extends Runnable{
        default String getId() {
            return "2";
        }
    }
    static class TestClass implements TestInterface {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("TEST");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
                String id = ((TestInterface)r).getId();
                Thread t = new Thread(r, id);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                return t;
            }
        });

        Stream.of(new TestClass(),new TestClass(),new TestClass(),new TestClass()).forEach(exec::submit);

    }
}
```

Comment: So basically using custom `threadfactory` is useless for me and I have to work with threads manually.

Comment: @lapots why did you want to use thread factory? So you can name your threads like your ids?

Comment: @lapots in the first line of your run() method simply do Thread.currentThread().setName(getId());

Comment: @Wow yeah I wanted to create custom ids using the objects inside the thread

Comment: @lapots Thread.currentThread().setName(getId()) won't work for you?

Comment: @Wow it probably will.