# How to specify ForkJoinPool for Java 8 parallel stream?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

As I know, the parallel streams use the default `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` which by default has one less threads than your processors. I want to use my own custom thread pool.

Like this:

```
@Test
public void stream() throws Exception {
    //System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "20");
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(10);
    List<Integer> testList = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Integer> result = pool.submit(() -> testList.parallelStream().map(item -> {
        try {
            // read from database
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("task" + item + ":" + Thread.currentThread());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return item * 10;
    })).get().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
}
```

And the result:
[image]

My custom `ForkJoinPool` is never used.
And I change the default parallelism like this:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "20");
```

It works well - the tasks cost only about 1 second.

In my application the task contains heavy IO operation (reading data from db).
So I need higher parallelism, but I do not want to change the JVM property.

So what is the right way to specify my own `ForkJoinPool`?

Or how to use parallel streams in IO-intensive situation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Streams are lazy; all work is done when you commence a terminal operation. In your case, the terminal operation is `.collect(Collectors.toList())`, which you call in the `main` thread on the result of `get()`. Therefore, the actual work will be done the same way as if you’ve constructed the entire stream in the `main` thread.

For your pool to have an effect, you have to move the terminal operation into the submitted task:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(10);
List<Integer> testList = Arrays.asList(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Integer> result = pool.submit(() -> testList.parallelStream().map(item -> {
    try {
        // read from database
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("task" + item + ":" + Thread.currentThread());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    return item * 10;
}).collect(Collectors.toList())).join();
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

We can also demonstrate the relevance of the terminal operation by constructing the stream in the `main` thread and only submitting the terminal operation to the pool:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = testList.parallelStream().map(item -> {
    try {
        // read from database
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("task" + item + ":" + Thread.currentThread());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    return item * 10;
});
List<Integer> result = pool.submit(() -> stream.collect(Collectors.toList())).join();
```

But you should keep in mind that this is undocumented behavior, which is not guaranteed. The actual answer must be that the Stream API in its current form, with no thread control (and no help for dealing with checked exceptions), is not suitable for parallel I/O operations.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you discovered the trick described here:

- [Custom thread pool in Java 8 parallel stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream)

which states

> The trick is based on `ForkJoinTask.fork` which specifies: *"Arranges to
>   asynchronously execute this task in the pool the current task is
>   running in, if applicable, or using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` if
>   not `inForkJoinPool()`"*

In your code, `parallelStream()` and `map(...)` are invoked in the custom `ForkJoinPool`, but the `Function` passed to `map` is not.

Remember that [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) is an intermediate operation. Its `Function` will only be executed for its element once a terminal operation is chained. In your case, that terminal operation is `collect(...)`. And since `collect(Collectors.toList()` is invoked in the `main` thread, the `map`'s `Function` is invoked on each element in parallel in the `commonPool`.

You could simply move the `collect(...)` call inside your `submit(...)`.

```
List<Integer> result = pool.submit(() -> testList.parallelStream().map(item -> {
    try {
        // read from database
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("task" + item + ":" + Thread.currentThread());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return item * 10;
}).collect(Collectors.toList())).get();
```