# How to Fan Out Inside Chained CompletableFuture?

Tags: java-8, parallel-processing, completable-future

I want to chain a CompletableFuture such that it fans out in the middle of processing. By this I mean I have an open CompletableFuture against a list, and I want to apply a computation against each item in that list.

The first step is to call *m_myApi.getResponse(request, executor)* which issues an async call.

The result of that async call has a *getCandidates* method. I want to parse all of those candidates in parallel.

Currently, my code parses them all serially

```
public CompletableFuture<List<DOMAIN_OBJECT>> parseAllCandidates(@Nonnull final REQUEST request, @Nonnull final Executor executor)
{
        CompletableFuture<RESPONSE> candidates = m_myApi.getResponse(request, executor);
        return candidates.thenApplyAsync(response -> response.getCandidates()
                                                   .stream()
                                                   .map(MyParser::ParseCandidates)
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

I want something like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<DOMAIN_OBJECT>> parseAllCandidates(@Nonnull final REQUEST request, @Nonnull final Executor executor)
{
        CompletableFuture<RESPONSE> candidates = m_myApi.getResponse(request, executor);
        return candidates.thenApplyAsync(response -> response.getCandidates()
                                                   .stream()
                                                   .PARSE_IN_PARALLEL_USING_EXECUTOR
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52999762/2711488), if the `Executor` happens to be a Fork/Join pool, there is the (undocumented) feature that commencing a parallel stream in one of its worker threads will perform the parallel operation using that executor.

When you want to support arbitrary `Executor` implementations, things are more complicated. One solution looks like

```
public CompletableFuture<List<DOMAIN_OBJECT>> parseAllCandidates(
       @Nonnull final REQUEST request, @Nonnull final Executor executor)
{
    CompletableFuture<RESPONSE> candidates = m_myApi.getResponse(request, executor);
    return candidates.thenComposeAsync(
        response -> {
            List<CompletableFuture<DOMAIN_OBJECT>> list = response.getCandidates()
                .stream()
                .map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
                .map(f -> f.thenApplyAsync(MyParser::ParseCandidates, executor))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]))
                .thenApplyAsync(x ->
                    list.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                    executor);
        },
        executor);
}
```

The first crucial thing is that we have to submit all potentially asynchronous jobs before starting to wait on any, to enable the maximum parallelism the executor might support. Hence, we have to collect all futures in a `List` in a first step.

In the second step, we could just iterate over the list and `join` all futures. If the executor is a Fork/Join pool and the future has not completed yet, it would detect this and start a compensation thread to regain the configured parallelism. However, for *arbitrary* executors, we can not assume such a feature. Most notable, if the executor is a single thread executor, this could lead to a deadlock.

Therefore, the solution uses `CompletableFuture.allOf` to perform the operation of iterating and joining all futures only when all of them have been completed already. Therefore, this solution will never block an executor’s thread, making it compatible with any `Executor` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There already is a version of `thenApply` that takes an `Executor` as additional argument.

```
<U> CompletionStage<U>  thenApplyAsync​(Function<? super T,​? extends U> fn, Executor executor)
```

If you pass a forkjoin executor there then a [parallel stream](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Parallelism) inside the lambda will [use the passed executor instead of the common pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21163108/1362755).