# Number of CPU cores for parallel stream Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing, java-stream, cpu

I have below out put from one of VM.

So, as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream/21172732#21172732), the parallel streams use the default `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` which by default has one less threads as you have processors, as returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`.

If I do `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`, then it always returns 1, but looking at below output,  number should have been more. 
What I am missing here?

> lscpu command output is :-

```
2019-02-05T20:20:33.813+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Architecture: x86_64
2019-02-05T20:20:33.813+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
2019-02-05T20:20:33.813+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Byte Order: Little Endian
2019-02-05T20:20:33.813+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] CPU(s): 4
2019-02-05T20:20:33.813+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
2019-02-05T20:20:33.814+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Thread(s) per core: 1
2019-02-05T20:20:33.814+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Core(s) per socket: 1
2019-02-05T20:20:33.819+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Socket(s): 4
2019-02-05T20:20:33.819+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] NUMA node(s): 1
2019-02-05T20:20:33.819+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
2019-02-05T20:20:33.819+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] CPU family: 6
2019-02-05T20:20:33.819+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Model: 58
2019-02-05T20:20:33.819+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Stepping: 0
2019-02-05T20:20:33.820+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] CPU MHz: 2599.998
2019-02-05T20:20:33.820+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] BogoMIPS: 5199.99
2019-02-05T20:20:33.820+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Hypervisor vendor: VMware
2019-02-05T20:20:33.820+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Virtualization type: full
2019-02-05T20:20:33.820+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] L1d cache: 32K
2019-02-05T20:20:33.820+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] L1i cache: 32K
2019-02-05T20:20:33.821+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] L2 cache: 256K
2019-02-05T20:20:33.821+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] L3 cache: 40960K
```

Comment: Not really sure what the question is. Is it that why you get `1` as output while the number of processors is `4`? And where are the streams involved currently in the question?

Comment: @nullpointer streams are useless indeed, but I really wonder if that is *really* what the OP seems when running `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` or `lscpu`...

Comment: Could it be that you are running `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` in the VM but `lscpu`  in the host system (not VM)?

Comment: @Eugene true, that's what made the question unclear to me actually.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki exactly my thought... is docker involved may be?

Comment: sorry for unclear questions:- So, I have app deployed on pcf and in that app I am trying to find out number of cores from "Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()". lscpu, I did programatically again in the same app. Like "Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);" and command passed is lscpu

Comment: what is `pcf` btw?

Comment: Pivotal cloud foundry

Answer (score 7):

You are most likely running the Java code inside a VM with limited number of vCPUs or in a container restricted by control groups (cgroups) while your `lscpu` command is run on the host machine.

Unless your JVM is affected by a bug (e.g. [JDK-8188310](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8188310) or [JDK-6515172](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6515172)), these numbers should be the same.

Do note that Java 10 improved resource management as per [Java Improvements for Docker Containers](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html#JDK-8146115) and introduced `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount` option. Javas 8 that you are currently using definitely doesn't handle all edge cases correctly.

Comment: my app is running inside pcf container.