# Can we improve performance on lists other than java 8 parallel streams

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, stream, java-stream

I have to dump data from somewhere by calling rest API which returns List.

1. First i have to get some List object from one rest api. Now used parallel stream and gone through each item with forEach.
2. Now on for each element i have to call some other api to get the data which returns again list and save the same list by calling another rest api.
3. This is taking around 1 Hour for 6000 records of step 1.

I tried like below:

```
restApiMethodWhichReturns6000Records
    .parallelStream().forEach(id ->{
       anotherMethodWhichgetsSomeDataAndPostsToOtherRestCall(id);
                       });


public void anotherMethodWhichgetsSomeDataAndPostsToOtherRestCall(String id) {

     sestApiToPostData(url,methodThatGetsListOfData(id));
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the performance of lists. It has to do with the speed of the REST services, or of your network, or both.

Comment: looks like you call other rest api sequentially, not concurrently.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Can you improve above code block. I have used parallel stream above. where did i write wrong?

Comment: @Pavan please provide the code of methods sestApiToPostData and methodThatGetsListOfData. They must be non-blocking.

Answer (score 3):

`parallelStream` can cause unexpected behavior some times. It uses a common `ForkJoinPool`. So if you have parallel streams somewhere else in the code, it may have a blocking nature for long running tasks. Even in the same stream if some tasks are time taking, all the worker threads will be blocked.

A good discussion on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream). Here you see some tricks to assign task specific ForkJoinPool.

First of all make sure your REST service is non-blocking.

One more thing you can do is to play with pool size by supplying `-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=4` to JVM.

Answer (score 1):

IF the API calls are blocking, even when you run them in parallel, you will be able to do just a few calls in parallel.

I would try out a solution using `CompletableFuture`.

The code would be something like this:

```java
List<CompletableFuture>> apiCallsFutures = restApiMethodWhichReturns6000Records
    .stream()
    .map(id -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getListOfData(id))    // Mapping the get list of data call to a Completable Future
                                 .thenApply(listOfData -> callAPItoPOSTData(url, listOfData))   // when the get list call is complete, the post call can be performed 
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

CompletableFuture[] completableFutures = apiCallsFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[apiCallsFutures.size()]); // CompletableFuture.allOf accepts only arrays :(

CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures); // Combine all the futures

all.get(); // perform calls
```

For more details about CompletableFutures, have a look over: https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture