# java parallelStreams on different machines

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have a function that is iterating the list using parallelStream in forEach is then calling an API with the the item as param. I am then storing the result in a hashMap.

```
    try {
            return answerList.parallelStream()
                    .map(answer -> getReplyForAnswerCombination(answer))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
            log.error("Error in generating final results.", e);
            return null;
        }
```

When I run it on laptop 1, it takes 1 hour.
But on laptop 2, it takes 5 hours.

Doing some basic research I found that the parallel streams use the default ForkJoinPool.commonPool which by default has one less threads as you have processors.

Laptop1 and laptop2 have different processors.

- Is there a way to find out how many streams that can run parallelly on Laptop1 and Laptop2?
- Can I use the suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172732/1176432) to safely increase the number of parallel streams in laptop2?

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
IntStream s = IntStream.range(0, 20);
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "20");
s.parallel().forEach(i -> {
    try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    System.out.print((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ");
});
```

Comment: How many streams that can run depends on your code, whether it exhaust the CPU completely or stalling on IO that can be opportunistically used by other thread etc. I'd suggest just creating a sample workload that takes minutes to finish, then tweak the thread count until you found the right balance. Ideally, your code can handle stalling while waiting for IO without the next thread trashing the cache, in which case the number of available threads plus one is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

## Project Loom

If you want maximum performance on threaded code that blocks (as opposed to CPU-bound code), then use virtual threads (fibers) provided in [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main). Preliminary builds are [available now](http://jdk.java.net/loom/), based on early-access Java 16.

### Virtual threads

Virtual threads can be *dramatically* faster because a virtual thread is “parked” while blocked, set aside, so another virtual thread can make progress. This is so efficient for blocking tasks that threads can number in the millions.

Drop the streams approach. Merely send off each input to a virtual thread.

### Full example code

Let's define classes for `Answer` and `Reply`, our inputs & outputs. We will use [`record`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), a new feature coming to Java 16, as an abbreviated way to define an immutable data-driven class. The compiler implicitly creates default implementations of constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
public record Answer (String text)
{
}
```

…and:

```java
public record Reply (String text)
{
}
```

Define our task to be submitted to an executor service. We write a class named `ReplierTask` that implements [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) (has a [`run`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html#run()) method).

Within the `run` method, we sleep the current thread to simulate waiting for a call to a database, file system, and/or remote service.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

public class ReplierTask implements Runnable
{
    private Answer answer;
    ConcurrentMap < Answer, Reply > map;

    public ReplierTask ( Answer answer , ConcurrentMap < Answer, Reply > map )
    {
        this.answer = answer;
        this.map = map;
    }

    private Reply getReplyForAnswerCombination ( Answer answer )
    {
        // Simulating a call to some service to produce a `Reply` object.
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 1 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }  // Simulate blocking to wait for call to service or db or such.
        return new Reply( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
    }

    // `Runnable` interface
    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "`run` method at " + Instant.now() + " for answer: " + this.answer );
        Reply reply = this.getReplyForAnswerCombination( this.answer );
        this.map.put( this.answer , reply );
    }
}
```

Lastly, some code to do the work. We make a class named `Mapper` that contains a `main` method.

We simulate some input by populating an array of `Answer` objects. We create an empty `ConcurrentMap` in which to collect the results. And we assign each `Answer` object to a new thread where we call for a new `Reply` object and store the `Answer`/`Reply` pair as an entry in the map.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Mapper
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println("Runtime.version(): " + Runtime.version() );
        System.out.println("availableProcessors: " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        System.out.println("maxMemory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() + " | maxMemory/(1024*1024) -> megs: " +Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/(1024*1024)  );
        Mapper app = new Mapper();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        // Simulate our inputs, a list of `Answer` objects.
        int limit = 10_000;
        List < Answer > answers = new ArrayList <>( limit );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ )
        {
            answers.add( new Answer( String.valueOf( i ) ) );
        }

        // Do the work.
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        System.out.println( "Starting work at: " + start + " on count of tasks: " + limit );
        ConcurrentMap < Answer, Reply > results = new ConcurrentHashMap <>();
        try
                (
                        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
                        // Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 )
                        // Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 )
                        // Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1_000 )
                        // Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor()
                )
        {
            for ( Answer answer : answers )
            {
                ReplierTask task = new ReplierTask( answer , results );
                executorService.submit( task );
            }
        }
        // At this point the flow-of-control blocks until all submitted tasks are done.
        // The executor service is automatically closed by this point as well.
        Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , Instant.now() );
        System.out.println( "results.size() = " + results.size() + ". Elapsed: " + elapsed );
    }
}
```

We can change out the `Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor()` with a pool of platform threads, to compare against virtual threads. Let's try a pool of 5, 10, and 1,000 platform threads on a Mac mini Intel with macOS Mojave sporting 6 real cores, no hyper-threading, 32 gigs of memory, and OpenJDK special build version 16-loom+9-316 assigned maxMemory of 8 gigs.

| 10,000 tasks at 1 second each | Total elapsed time |
| --- | --- |
| 5 platform threads | half-hour — PT33M29.755792S |
| 10 platform threads | quarter-hour — PT16M43.318973S |
| 1,000 platform threads | 10 seconds — PT10.487689S |
| 10,000 platform threads | Error… unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached |
| virtual threads | Under 3 seconds — PT2.645964S |

### Caveats

Caveat: Project Loom is experimental and subject to change, not intended for production use yet. The team is asking for folks to give feedback now.

Caveat: CPU-bound tasks such as encoding video should stick with platform/kernel threads rather than virtual threads. Most common code doing blocking operations such as I/O, like accessing files, logging, hitting a database, or making network calls, will likely see massive performance boosts with virtual threads.

Caveat: You must have enough memory available for many or even all of your tasks to be running simultaneously. If not enough memory will be available, you must take additional steps to throttle the virtual threads.

Comment: Basically, you are providing a solution using an `ExecutorService` instead of the Stream API. This solution would work fine even without Project Loom using an ordinary thread pool executor. The OP showed an example trying to use 20 threads. Even using 1,000 threads does not necessarily require virtual threads to run smoothly. Mentioning Project Loom as an upcoming solution to scale up even with million threads is a nice addition, but there is no need to make your solution dependent on it.

Comment: @Holger The author’s concern was performance, how long it takes to accomplish all the tasks in total. If the code in question blocks, you will see a *huge* difference in total time using virtual threads. Quite possibly minutes rather than the hours cited in the Question. You have to see virtual threads in action to believe it. So, yes, virtual threads is the entire point of my Answer, not executor service in general.

Comment: @Holger Your comment prompted me to do some experimenting. I changed my example code to add a 1 second sleep in each task to simulate some blocking activity. Then I ran with various executor services to compare virtual threads versus platform threads. Virtual threads ran this example at least 3 times faster than the 1,000 platform threads you suggested. With smaller thread pools, the performance gap is far wider. See fresh code and results table in my updated Answer.

Comment: The result will surely be less dramatic with task doing actual work rather than sleep, but that’s not the point. Your experiments demonstrated, that you can easily change the executor, so even if an ordinary thread pool might perform worse than virtual threads, it performs better than the OP’s approach and may be sufficient *today*. So it’s a pity that you create the impression that your answer was not usable without Loom and the OP had to wait for it to become a production feature. You are unnecessarily restricting the usefulness of your own answer.

Comment: Loom is going to be very helpful in future but this particular test is rigged heavily in favour of LOOM because of the sleep(1second) which LOOM can run pretty much at the same time across all threads. Without the sleep included, LOOM speed is generally 2nd or 3rd place of the suggestions (vs 5 / 10 real threads).

Comment: @DuncG Look at my first sentence. Look at my second caveat. I explained in the my Answer that virtual threads shine when used with code that blocks. For purely CPU-bound tasks, use platform/kernel threads. Most common business app code involves blocking for logging, database queries, storage I/O, and network calls. For those, use virtual threads. So my test was not rigged.The call to `Thread.sleep` simulates such common blocking. The fact that “LOOM can run pretty much at the same time across all threads” is precisely my point.

Answer (score 1):

The setting `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` will have an effect on the threads available to use for operations which make use of the `ForkJoinPool`, such as `Stream.parallel()`. However: whether your task uses more threads depends on the number of items in the stream, and whether it takes less time to run depends on the nature of each task and your available processors.

This test program shows the effect of changing this system property with a trivial task:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> threads = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    int max     = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    boolean parallel = args.length < 2 || !"single".equals(args[1]);
    int [] arr = IntStream.range(0, max).toArray();

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(arr);
    if (parallel)
        stream = stream.parallel();
    stream.forEach(i -> {
        threads.put("hc="+Thread.currentThread().hashCode()+" tn="+Thread.currentThread().getName(), "value");
    });
    long end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("parallelism: "+System.getProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism"));
    System.out.println("Threads: "+threads.keySet());
    System.out.println("Array size: "+arr.length+" threads used: "+threads.size()+" ms="+TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end-start));
}
```

Adding more threads won't necessarily speed things up. Here are some examples from test run to count the threads used. It may help you decide on best approach for your own task contained in `getReplyForAnswerCombination()`.

```
java -cp example.jar -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1000 App 100000
Array size: 100000 threads used: 37

java -cp example.jar -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=50 App  100000
Array size: 100000 threads used: 20

java -cp example.jar APP 100000 single
Array size: 100000 threads used: 1
```

I suggest you see the thread pooling (with or without LOOM) in @Basil Bourque answer and also the JDK source code of the ForkJoinPool constructor has some details on this system property.

```
private ForkJoinPool(byte forCommonPoolOnly)
```