# Why does my Flux stream running in parallel skipping some records?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to understand `Flux.parallel()` working.
My requirement is as follows:
There is a list of String `stringList`, and let's say we are doing some task on each string in parallel and one of the string takes some time, for instance here I am using `Thread.sleep`, then I want to collect the string in `Flux<String>`, but before this I need to make sure if the execution for all the strings in parallel is finished.

In the following code, it is skipping the string `Mango`, why is that?
And if I use `blockLast()` then it is not skipping but if I use `blockLast()`, it won't give return `Flux<String>`.
Also, What is the difference between `sequential` and `blockLast`?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Mango", "Apple", "Grapes", "Java");
Flux<String> flust = Flux.fromIterable(list)
  .parallel(10)
  .runOn(Schedulers.parllel(), list.size())
  .map(string -> {
     if(string.equals("Mango")) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      //some task
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + string);
      return string;
    })
   .sequential();
flust.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

OUTPUT :

parallel-2 Apple

parallel-4 Java

parallel-3 Grapes

Apple

Grapes

Java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom thread pool in Java 8 parallel stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream)

Comment: @K.Nicholas No it doesn't the example is of Java Stream, here I am using Reactive Stream. Also, both of the streams have different operators.

Comment: I'll give you a point for that comment.

Comment: could you please explain more about `Schedulers.fromExecutorService(process.getExecutor())` what is `process` and what does `getExecutor` return

Comment: Is the current thread blocking until the subscriber has completed processing? When I run with .parallel().runOn(Schedulers.parallel()) with a Thread.sleep(2000) at the end I see all fruit.

Comment: @Toerktumlare process is nothing but a component, and process.getExecutor() just return a ThreadPoolExecutor manually configured.

Comment: @LeeGreiner No Mango is not there.

Comment: Well show us the missing code as this code can not be run and i cant reproduce your claims using the standard parallell executor.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have edited the code, Still the result it same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the Reactor [javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-) subscribe method:

> Keep in mind that since the sequence can be asynchronous, this will
> immediately return control to the calling thread. This can give the
> impression the consumer is not invoked when executing in a main thread
> or a unit test for instance.

This means that the end of the main method is reached, and thus the main thread exits before the `Mango`  element is consumed.

To solve this, you can use `blockLast()` instead of `subscribe()` and trigger the side-effect (printing) within `doOnNext` method:

```
    Flux<String> flust = Flux.fromIterable(list)
        .parallel(10)
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel(), list.size())
        .map(string -> {
            if (string.equals("Mango")) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //some task
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + string);
            return string;
        })
        .sequential()
        .doOnNext(System.out::println);

    flust.blockLast();
```

Here, you block execution on the main thread until the last element on the `Flux` is processed.

Comment: Yes, blockLast() will do the work, But I want to understand why is this. happening in the first place, why is it skipping "Mango"?

Comment: @JavaProgrammer Edit made.