# How to limit number of parallel executions in ParallelStream?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

```
list.parallelStream().forEach(element -> ...);
```

How can I limit the number of parallel threads nowadays?

There was a "hack" in the past to set a System property `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism`. But that feels wrong, plus it does not work anymore.

Could you advise how to **chunk** the list into 4 divisions, and then only run those 4 devisions in parallel?

Comment: “it does not work anymore”—really? Which Java version are you referring to?

Comment: Jdk14. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but apart from, that I'd also don't want to change the parallelism throughout the application. But just throttle one specific stream.

Comment: Does it have to be a Stream operation? After all, you’re only using `forEach` in your example and literally asked “how to chunk the list into 4 divisions” which is actually a trivial operation. Unless you need a specific Stream feature.

Comment: @Holger ok that's true, but then the question still remains how to execute 4 divided lists in parallel... With or without streams.

Comment: `int a = 0, e = list.size(), c = e >>> 1, b = c >>> 1, d = e - b; executorService.invokeAll(Arrays.asList( Executors.callable(() -> list.subList(a, b) .forEach(action)), Executors.callable(() -> list.subList(b, c).forEach(action)), Executors.callable(() -> list.subList(c, d).forEach(action)), Executors.callable(() -> list.subList(d, e).forEach(action)) ));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you rather need to limit the number of concurrent tasks being executed, therefore I don't find a necessity of using a parallel stream here as long as there is an easy solution located in the Java concurrent package. Use `ExecutorService` with a fixed thread pool of four instead.

```
Collection<Callable<Void>> = ...
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
executorService.invokeAll(callables);
```

If you really wish to use a custom thread pool within the parallel streams, please, refer to this question: [Custom thread pool in Java 8 parallel stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21163108/3764965).

Comment: It's a but ugly that you have to `return null` inside a `Callable<Void>`. But apart from that, it works!

Comment: @membersound use `Executors.callable(() -> …)`

Comment: @Holger: that was probably the missing piece, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Use custom thread pool.

Read more here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool

and here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-when-to-use-parallel-stream

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom ForkJoinPool with the number of needed threads to execute your task in parallel.

```
ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(NB_THREADS);
customThreadPool.submit(
() -> list.parallelStream().forEach(element -> ...);
```