# Simple multi-threaded Java app - ExecutorService? Fork/Join? Spliterators?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, fork-join, spliterator

I am writing a command-line application in Java 8. There's a part that involves some computation, and I believe it could benefit from running in parallel using multiple threads. However, I have not much experience in writing multi-threaded applications, so I hope you could steer me in the right direction how should I design the parallel part of my code.

For simplicity, let's pretend the method in question receives a relatively big array of longs, and it should return a Set containing only prime numbers:

```
public final static boolean checkIfNumberIsPrime(long number) {
  // algorithm implementation, not important here
  // ...
}

// a single-threaded version
public Set<Long> extractPrimeNumbers(long[] inputArray) {
  Set<Long> result = new HashSet<>();
  for (long number : inputArray) {
    if (checkIfNumberIsPrime(number)) {
      result.add(number);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now, I would like to refactor method `extractPrimeNumbers()` in such way that it would be executed by four threads in parallel, and when all of them are finished, return the result. Off the top of my head, I have the following questions:

- Which approach would be more suitable for the task: `ExecutorService` or Fork/Join? (each element of `inputArray[]` is completely independent and they can be processed in any order whatsoever)
- Assuming there are 1 million elements in `inputArray[]`, should I "ask" thread #1 to process all indexes 0..249999, thread #2 - 250000..499999, thread #3 - 500000..749999 and thread #4 - 750000..999999? Or should I rather treat each element of `inputArray[]` as a separate task to  be queued and then executed by an applicable worker thread?
- If a prime number is detected, it should be added to `Set result, therefore it needs to be thread-safe (synchronized). So, perhaps it would be better if each thread maintained its own, local result-set, and only when it is finished, it would transfer its contents to the global result, in one go?
- Is `Spliterator` of any use here? Should they be used to partition `inputArray[]` somehow?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to asking one question per question. As it stands, your question is a bit broad and unfocused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Parallel stream

Use none of these.  Parallel streams are going to be enough to deal with this problem much more straightforwardly than any of the alternatives you list.

```
return Arrays.parallelStream(inputArray)
  .filter(n -> checkIfNumberIsPrime(n))
  .boxed()
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

For more info, see *The Java™ Tutorials* > *Aggregate Operations* > [*Parallelism*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html).

Comment: Could the filter use a method reference? `.filter( WhateverClass :: checkIfNumberIsPrime )`

Comment: Thanks! But how would I control how many threads are used to execute **parallelStream()**? As far as I understand, they should correspond to processor cores...

Comment: @BasilBourque: Yes, but the OP didn't give enough information to determine the name of the class.

Comment: @LeszekPachura: You can as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269778/869736), but you shouldn't.  `parallelStream` will figure out the right number of threads for you.