# Parallel Stream with virtual threads: Java VirtualThread equivalent for ForkJoinWorkerThread

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm experimenting with Java virtual threads and wonder if it's possible to run parallel `Stream`s with virtual threads. By default, parallel streams are run on the common `ForkJoinPool`, but one could use a custom thread pool by calling a `Stream`'s terminal operation on the worker thread of another `ForkJoinPool`. But as of JDK 20, `ForkJoinPool` can only manage threads of `ForkJoinWorkerThread` instances.

Is there a `VirtualThread` equivalent for `ForkJoinWorkerThread`? Or is there an alternative way to run tasks in a work-stealing manner using virtual threads?

Comment: That’s not foreseen and it’s not clear what you hope to gain from that.

Comment: This would be desired, in conjunction with https://stackoverflow.com/q/21163108 , because we may want to have thousands and thousands of threads running at the same time. One of my particular processing use cases may have most of those threads blocked with I/O at any given time. Wouldn't native threads have a needless overhead? Wouldn't it be a benefit in this scenario to use the elegant model of `stream.parallel().…` implemented using virtual threads? Or is there something that would prevent `stream.parallel().…` from utilizing so many threads?